# Get File from Google cloud storage bucket using RestSharp or C#

Tags: c#, get, restsharp, google-cloud-storage

i am trying to download file from  .
For downloading i am using rest Sharp API but not succeeded, before it have tried  following line of code but still not succeed

```
 Dim dwn As ObjectsResource.GetRequest = New ObjectsResource.GetRequest(storageService, "dfa_-xxxxxx", "kkkk_07-xx-20xx.log.gz")
 Dim stm As FileStream = New FileStream(Server.MapPath("DFA/kkkk_07-xx-20xx.log.gz"), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)
 dwn.Download(stmRead)//Not working
```

Please suggest what should i do .

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.ProtocolException: Error occurred while sending a direct message or getting the response

Answer (score 0):

I got a C# Project "SharpGS".It works fine and Crate & delete buckets,download objects.

http://oleksiy.pro/2010/06/17/google-storage-api-with-c-sharpgs-try-it/

Here are two keys to be use . Login your Google API console and then click "Here" link in given article's point 2 . It will redirect to you Google Cloud Storage tab ,see in footer and activate interoperable Storage Access and active it . Now you can see Access and Secrete Key (term use in project AuthKey /AuthSecret )